# KeyError + POST + Django Rest Framework

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm new on Django Rest Framework and when I want to POST data and I get this error **KeyError at /api/ 'folder'**.
Here's my code:
in my models.py

```
class Folder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Todo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    folder = models.ForeignKey('Folder', related_name='todos', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

in my serializers.py

```
class FolderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id','name',)
        model = models.Folder
        extra_kwargs = {
            "id":{
                "required":False, 
                "read_only":False
                }
            }

class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    folder = FolderSerializer(read_only=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id','title','description','folder',)
        model = models.Todo

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Get our folder
        folder_data = validated_data.pop('folder')
        # Create our todo
        todo = models.Todo.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for data in folder_data:
            models.Folder.objects.create(todo=todo, **data)
        return todo
```

And in my views.py

```
class  ListTodo(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.Todo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.TodoSerializer
```

The problem is that when I want to Post data like:
    {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "Python",
            "description": "Learn python lesson",
            "folder": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Lesson"
            }
        }
I got this error
**folder_data = validated_data.pop('folder')
KeyError: 'folder'**
I need some help please

Comment: It would help if you could talk about what you've tried, and what you've done to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I would like to post data like what I put in my post:{ "id": 4, "title": "Python", "description": "Learn python lesson", "folder": { "id": 1, "name": "Lesson" } }. I test my project on Postman and I can Get data but when I try to Post I got this error folder_data = validated_data.pop('folder') KeyError: 'folder'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **Key error** raises because you have set `read_only=True` for the folder in the `TodoSerializer`. So `validated_data` will not contain `folder` key. And also you can't use `required=False` for the folder. Because your `Todo` model definition says folder is required field. So to make it work, rewrite your serializer as follow

```
class FolderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id','name',)
        model = models.Folder

class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    folder = FolderSerializer()
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id','title','description','folder',)
        model = models.Todo

    def create(self, validated_data):
        folder_data = validated_data.pop('folder')
        folder = models.Folder.objects.create(**folder_data)
        todo = models.Todo.objects.create(folder=folder, **validated_data)
        return todo
```

**NOTE**: Since you are using `serializers.ModelSerializer`, you don't have to write `extra_kwargs` conditions for the serializer. ModelSerializer itself creates from the model.`extra_kwargs` is only used to **override** the models default behaviour in the serializer.